# How to obtain statically linked dll dependencies automatically

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dependency-management

When creating new projects I've always stumbled upon the issue that my final executable or dll does not properly run because it is missing dependencies I was using.

In my live as a developer I've seen several approaches to handle that (of which I don't like any)

- Set environment path to all those dependencies so that the OS can find them (bad, since very unportable, requires environment, won't work out of the box)
- Copy every dependency of a potentially large package into the binary output directory (e.g. dozens of dlls regardless of need). For dependencies like OSG, Qt, etc this is quite odd as you typically won't link all dlls provided by larger packages and you may end up copying much more data than necessary.
- Hand-Pick single dependencies (and optionally their pdbs) with a fine-grained xcopy/robocopy or whatever task. (Don't like that as it needs attention, I add a dependency in Visual Studio and then I need to adjust some script). There are tools like dependency walker which help this, but still, this might still be unportable because your include path in VS may have a version in it, if you change that, you need to change it also in the script, which is too much `Department of Redundancy Department`

In larger projects or companies I would expect this issue to be quite common. Is their nothing in Visual Studio or in Windows that aids that? I need to pick my include paths and import lib paths properly in order to compile a binary but then I need some other mechanism to actually make things work.

I am thinking about solving this problem in a more general way for more projects but really wonder if I am missing something.

Comment: See:  http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: At home and at work I use `CMake` to generate my Visual Studio project files and have it collect all the dependencies and add them to the installer it generates for my applications. With that said its a lot of time/work to learn `CMake`. I am not sure I would recommend it for just this feature anyways.

Comment: With my above comment my approach with `CMake` is somewhere between your second and third bullet for example in the case of Qt. My `CMake` script knows (by me telling it / setting a `CMake` variable) I am using QtCore, QtSql ... so when generating the package my CMake macro knows what dlls for Qt to add to the list of dependencies. Although with that said CMake does have an automatic way to determine the dependent dlls. I generally don't use that however.

Comment: @RichardCritten my third bullet literally uses the word dependency walker.

Comment: @drescherjm The funny thing is: I came up with this question while refactoring a project away from CMake because I find it very awful (>7 years of working with it) and it does not really copy things to output dir.

Comment: My `CMake` scripts/ macros copy the dependencies using a target.

Comment: I remember doing similar before I used `CMake` (since 2008) although back then it was a combination of utilities I wrote + manual steps to collect the dependencies.